# Setting the column gap in a twocolumn (or multicol) document

Tags: spacing, two-column, multicol

I have a document that uses `twocolumn` with `scrbook`. How can I set the width of the space between the two columns?

Comment: Why was there a -1 vote?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use `\setlength{\columnsep}{<width>}` in the preamble of your document, i.e. before \begin{document}.

Changing `\columnsep` also works if you use the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package.

Comment: I used \setlength{\columnsep}{5 in} but it didn't make any difference. I'm a beginner to latex. I think there's a problem with dimensions. Please help.

Comment: In the case of the `multicol` package, the `\setlength` command need not necessarily appear in the preamble; it can appear inside the body as well, as long as it precedes the `\multicols` or `multicols*` environment that it is intended to apply to. Consider, for instance, a document with two `\multicols` environments. These environments can have different inter-column spaces, but then the `\columnsep` parameter *must* be set *inside* the body.

Comment: Thank you, but no matter where in the document I set it—in the preamble, in the body, before the environment, after the environment (which wouldn't make sense anyway, but I tried it just in case)—this command has no effect on my document. The columns always stay quite far apart. Nor does setting the width make a difference, as suggested by Muaz Khan below. I am using 
\begin{multicols}{3}.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem earlier today.  As Mauz Khan and Evan Aad note, the solution of adding  `\setlength{\columnsep}{<width>}` to the preamble or in the body (prior to starting the multicol environment) does not always work. If you are in certain modes (Beamer, for instance) where `\usepackage{multicol}` is being called in your .sty file (rather that in the preamble of your actual document), modifying `\columnsep` in your document's preamble will not work.  In this case, you would need to modify the length in the preamble of the .sty file by adding `\setlength{\columnsep}{<width>}` there instead, rather than in your document.

I hope this helps someone else!  Perhaps its more of a comment, but this is what I am limited to.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is more of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145190)

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob, I think it is worth leaving here because the accepted answer will not work in all cases, as I have noted above.  Sorry for the ambiguity!

Comment: If you set it to a negative value, e.g.

\setlength{\columnsep}{-3.0mm}

it should work.

Answer (score 3):

As meteors mentioned in his comment, `\setlength{\columnsep}{5 in}` also did not work for me. I was using `\twocolumn` command. Instead of separating the two column, I adjusted the widths of each column and it did work out well i.e.,

```
\setlength{\columnwidth}{<width>}
```