# How to change columns distance?

Tags: spacing, two-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the column gap in a twocolumn document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24561/setting-the-column-gap-in-a-twocolumn-document)

How can I change the distance of two columns in a two-column document?

Comment: Have a look at [Setting the column gap in a twocolumn document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24561/setting-the-column-gap-in-a-twocolumn-document). Please tell us in a comment, if it helped, so we can close this question here as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Thank you very much Stefan Kottwitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the internal definition of `\twocolumn`. In this definition you can see all length which are use.

```
\def \twocolumn {%
  \clearpage
  \global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
  \global\divide\columnwidth\tw@
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
  \global\@twocolumntrue
  \global\@firstcolumntrue
  \col@number \tw@
  \@ifnextchar [\@topnewpage\@floatplacement
}
```

Taken from `latex.ltx`

You are looking for `\columnsep`.